# summarize_at() for colums with backslash not working

Tags: r

I have a given df which has some column names that include a "/" (e.g. "Province/State" and "Country/Region").

I want to first group the df by "Country/Region" and then summarize it like this:

```
confirmed_by_country <- confirmed %>%
  group_by("Country/Region") %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(-Lat, -Long, -"Province/State"), sum)
```

When I try to run this code it tells me that the column "Province/State" does not exist. I was warned about using this problem but still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am also confused why I am only getting this error for "Province/State" and not "Country/Region" in the group_by() function.

does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? Thanks!

Comment: Post a sample of your data by giving us the output of dput()

Comment: Use back tick around Province/State

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it made a difference whether I imported the data with `read.csv()` or `read_csv()`.

It didn't work with `read.csv()` even if I used backticks but it did when I used `read_csv()` and backticks. (The column names were also different depending on which one I used.)

If anyone knows why that is, I'm interested!

Comment: We can't know why the two functions worked differently because you haven't given us a minimal reporducible example.  But it's good that you found a solution.  Also, note that `summarise_at` (and other scoped `dplyr` verbs) have been superseded by `across`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).